# Why can't I clone Azure Dev Ops repo over SSH?

Tags: git, azure-devops

An organization I work for has a git repo hosted in Azure Dev Ops.  I have access to this repo, and I can clone it over https.  However, I want to use ssh instead.  In the security tab of Azure Dev Ops, I have added the public key from the .ssh folder on my machine to my account.  I did not expect to have to do anything further, but when I try to clone I get prompted for a password, which I did not expect.  The password I use for https access does not work.  Nor does my login password, and I wind up with a session that looks like this...

```
git clone myorg@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/myorg/my%20org%20project1.0/myrepo

Cloning into 'myrepo'...
myorg@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
myorg@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
myorg@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com's password:
myorg@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com: Permission denied (password,publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Why is it asking for a password?  Why am denied access?

Comment: Did you start by referring to the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts

Comment: either private key mismatch or you didnt add the proper public key, i'd say. as soon as you add proper key it should work (if you have enough permissions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, if using a non-default key (i.e. not C:/users/username/.ssh/id_rsa) then you must run the script `ssh-add.cmd` included in your Git for Windows installation and then (and this is the part that was tripping me up) clone the repo from *the same shell window*.  I was trying to run the clone command in a second command prompt window which did not get the benefit of ssh-add.

Looking at the contents of `ssh-add.cmd`, it appears that it works by setting a temporary SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable, so this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is an issue with the clone URL. To help Windows with the way it does it's Credential Manager they've included `myorg@` in the clone URL. So this turns into the username.

If you use the clone url without the `myorg@` it will likely work.